# Change column divs to rows

Tags: html, css

I have this tumblr theme: http://flataura.tumblr.com/
When you click on a post, the post appears as a lightbox with two columns, one with the image and the other with the content.

What I would like to do is that only for mobiles, that order changes.
I want the image to be on top of the text content (that would end up below the image). I´m not an expert but I manage to solve things on my own and I did my fair hours of research on the subject but I couldn't find a solution for this.

Below an example image. Thank you in advance!

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zguK.jpg)

Comment: Hey can you edit that theme on tumblr i.e. CSS code if so then remove float:left from this code
 tc_post_perma .rightcontent {
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 14px;
}

Comment: @frnt It was so easy, I can´t believe it!! thank you SO much!!
Do you by the way know how can I do this only on certain devices sizes?
Because I used the @ media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
 line but it didn´t seem to work with that.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome @LTart.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use flex. Add to parent div "display: flex" and "flex-direction:column". 
[More](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)